# Item_Send event not firing for Outlook 2010 .oft template

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I have written a very simple `Item_Send` handler for an outlook mail message template stored as an `oft` file that I run via a Macro:

```
Function Item_Send()
    MsgBox "hello"
    Item_Send = False
End Function
```

This event is not firing: I see no message box and the message sends.

Can anyone explain why this would be and how I can fix it?

Comment: The name of the event is the ItemSend. There is no whitespaces or underscores. Moreover, you need to specify parameters: the method should accept the item object and a boolean value.

Answer (score -1):

There is a built-in ItemSend you can use in "ThisOutlookSession" module like this.

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, _
                                  Cancel As Boolean) 
    If item.subject = "subject of the template" then
        MsgBox "hello"
        Cancel = True 
   End if
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a global event handler.. He needs something specific to his template!

Comment: @Dino `If item.subject = "subject of the template" then` or other identifying characteristic.

Comment: so subject here is not the subject of the email. the name of the template? Anyways I solved my issue by adding registry values to enable script running for custom forms.

Comment: If the template has a unique subject that passes to the email, that would indicate the message was created using the template. Otherwise some other identifier unique to the template that is in the mail would be needed.